# Soft: Looking for resource point-wise convergence and tightness implies convergence in probability uniformly

Tags: probability, random-variables

I came a across a proof that is trying to prove

$$X_t(\theta) \to 0 \text{ in probability} $$ uniformly, wrt $\theta$
where $X_t$ is a non-negative random variable.

The proof states that it is sufficient to prove point-wise convergence and the tightness of the sequence $\{X_t\}_{t\ge 0}$.

Looking for a resource that can give me some insight into this claim.

Edit:

Consider

$$X_t(\theta) = \lvert \varepsilon \int_0^1 f(Y_s,\theta)1_{\{s \leq \tau \}}dW_s \rvert $$
where $W_s$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\tau$ is a stopping time. Taking the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

The proof give the pointwise convergence by using Chebyshev's inequality and another proof for the tightness.

How do these two established facts ensure the convergence in probability uniformly wrt $\theta$?

Comment: Use Prohoro's Theorem.

Comment: Does “point-wise convergence” mean almost-sure convergence? If so, no need for tightness. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $t_n \rightarrow 0$ be a decreasing positive sequence. Then $P(|X_{t_n}| \leq \epsilon) \geq P(E_n)$, where $E_n$ is the event: “$\forall m \geq n,\, |X_{t_m}| \leq \epsilon$”. Now, $E_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence of events whose reunion is almost certain, so $P(E_n) \rightarrow 1$, thus $P(|X_{t_n}| \leq \epsilon) \rightarrow 1$, hence the convergence in probability.

Comment: @Aphelli I typed up the wrong thing, I've made an edit.

Comment: Did I get this correctly? Each $X_t$ is a *function-valued* random variable (in which space? $C^0$ for the usual $\sigma$-algebra?), and you want to show that, for the uniform distance, the sequence $X_t$ converges in probability to zero. Your source says that it’s enough to show tightness and almost sure pointwise convergence to zero (or maybe the reverse here), and you want to know why.

Comment: $f \in C^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}\times\Theta; \mathbb{R})$ and for the usual $\sigma$-algebra, nothing of special note there, and yeah uniform for $\theta \in \Theta$.

Comment: And that's the limit as what goes to what ? $t$ goes to something ?

Comment: @justt the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: How does $X_{t}(\theta)$ depends on $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: @justt $$X_t(\theta) = \lvert \varepsilon \int_0^1 f(Y_s,\theta)1_{\{s \leq \tau \}}dW_s \rvert  $$

Comment: Gotcha. And the tightness is the tightness of what, in what space ? What exactly do they prove ?

Comment: They say the tightness of $\{X_t\}$ wrt to $\varepsilon$. They prove it by proving two bounds 

$$E[X_t^{2q}(\theta)] \leq C  $$ and 
$$E[|X_t(\theta_1)-X_t(\theta_2)|^{2q}] \leq C|\theta_1 - \theta_2|^{2q}  $$. Doesn't say what space exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to piece the question together before I answer it.

Define

$$X_{t,\varepsilon}(\theta) = \lvert \varepsilon \int_0^1 f(Y_s,\theta)1_{\{s \leq \tau \}}dW_s \rvert$$

From what I gather, $t$ is completely fixed beforehand, you don't want uniformity in $t$. Actually I don't even see the dependency of $X_{t,\varepsilon}(\theta)$ in $t$ in its definition.

You have

- $X_{t,\varepsilon}(\theta) \to 0$ in probability as $\varepsilon \to 0$ for every fixed $\theta$.
- The family of random functions $(X_{t,\varepsilon})_{\varepsilon >0}$ is tight in the space $\mathcal C_0(\Theta)$ of continuous functions of variable $\theta$.
- I assume moreover that $\Theta$ is compact, otherwise I'm not sure this works.

In that case, $(X_{t,\varepsilon})_{\varepsilon}$ is relatively compact for the convergence in distribution in the space $\mathcal C_0(\Theta)$ (Prokhorov's theorem).

Assume a subsequence $(\varepsilon_k)_k$ going to $0$ and a limiting random function $Y$ such that $X_{t,\varepsilon_k} \to Y$ as $k\to\infty$ in distribution  in the space $\mathcal C_0(\Theta)$. Then for every fixed $\theta$ $X_{t,\varepsilon_k}(\theta) \to Y(\theta)$ in distribution. But because of the pointwise convergence we know that this limit is the random variable $0$.

So for every $\theta$, $Y(\theta) = 0$ in distribution, because it's deterministic, that's an almost-sure equality. Being a continuous function, we have almost surely that $Y=0$ everywhere.

Finally we have shown that a sublimit in distribution of $(X_{t,\varepsilon})_{\varepsilon}$ in the space $\mathcal C_0(\Theta)$ is necessarily the $0$ function.

By relative compactness this shows that $X_{t,\varepsilon} \to 0$ in distribution in the space $\mathcal C_0(\Theta)$. Convergence in distribution to a deterministic random variable is the same as convergence in probability, so $X_{t,\varepsilon} \to 0$ in probability in $\mathcal C_0(\Theta)$.

More explicitely, $$ P\left(\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} |X_{t,\varepsilon}| > \delta \right) \xrightarrow[\varepsilon \to 0]{} 0 \text{ for every } \delta$$

This is the uniform convergence you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that the $X_t$ are random variables with values in $C^0(T)$, where $T$ is a compact metric space, and it is endowed with the usual $\sigma$-algebra (the smallest one making all evaluations measurable).

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

We know that there exists a compact $0 \in K\subset C^0$ such that $P(X_t \notin K) \leq \epsilon/2$ for any $t >0$.

By Ascoli, there is a finite set $F \subset T$ such that if $f,g \in K$, we have $\|f-g\|_{\infty} \leq \epsilon/2+\|(f-g)_{|F}\|_{\infty}$.

It follows that $P(\|X_t\|_{\infty} > \epsilon) \leq \epsilon/2 + P(X_t \in K, \|(X_t)_{|F}\|_{\infty} \geq \epsilon/2) \leq \epsilon/2+\sum_{x \in F}{P(|X_t(x)| \geq \epsilon/2)}$.

For small enough $t$, the RHS is less than $\epsilon$ (because we have pointwise convergence, so every $X_t(x)$, for $x \in K$, converges in probability to $0$), QED.

Comment: You are supposed to show some uniformity in a parameter $\theta$ here...

Comment: @justt: I wrote it at the beginning: the $X_t$ are random functions. The $\theta$ is the argument. This is basically the same argument as yours, with slightly different notation and some different “big words”, and we are proving the same end result.

Comment: You're absolutely right.